# Moving image via css

Tags: css, image, location

I am beginning my first project that I want to end as an actual publish-able website for a relative who owns a metal shop.  I have gone through a bunch of FreeCodeCamp classes and researched things online myself but I'm very new to the whole thing!

I can't figure out how to move the company logo in the upper left hand corner higher to the top (vertically centered in the header area).  I've tried changing margins and padding and can't figure anything out.  I would love some assistance!  Thank you!!!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Style the header */
.header {
background: #0f2027; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #0f2027, #203a43, #2c5364); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0f2027, #203a43, #2c5364); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.toplogo {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  top: 0px;
}

.header > p {
  margin: 10px;
}

.header > h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

/* Style the top navigation bar */
.nav {
  width: 100vw;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
  transition: 0.2s;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: black;
    /*linear-gradient(to bottom, #d5d7e5, white, #F5F5F5, #d5d7e5);*/
  transition: background 0.5s ease out;
}

/* Style the topnav links */
.nav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
  }

/* Change color on hover */
.nav a:hover {
  background: #203a43;
    /*linear-gradient(to bottom, #43ff04, #eeffeb, #43ff04);*/

 }

/* Create three unequal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Left and right column */
.column.side {
  width: 25%;
}
 
/* Middle column */
.column.middle {
  width: 50%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column.side, .column.middle {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* Style the footer */
.footer {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Kidd Machine Works, LLC</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
 
  <!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
  (function(){
  var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  s1.async=true;
  s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/5ef7d1e34a7c6258179b774b/default';
  s1.charset='UTF-8';
  s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
  s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
  })();
  </script>
  <!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
  
<body>

<div class="header">
  <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5e306e33d98f3f2f031d3189/t/5e98f0d57b48315dcd70ed0e/1587085078151/?format=1500w" id = "logo" alt = "logo" class = "toplogo"/>
  <h3>Kidd Machine Works</h3>
  <p>123 Machine Way <br> Christiansburg, VA 24068</p>
  
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <nav>
  <li><a href="#" class="navbtn">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="navbtn">Machines</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="navbtn">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="navbtn">Quote</a></li>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column side">
    <h2>Side</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column middle">
    <h2>Main Content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column side">
    <h2>Side</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

[codepen page](https://codepen.io/matt-schucker/pen/ExPLPrq?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work?:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/CYr1/pen/pogOdrB)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Style the header */
.header {
background: #0f2027; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #0f2027, #203a43, #2c5364); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0f2027, #203a43, #2c5364); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.toplogo {
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header > p {
  margin: 10px;
} 

.header:before{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.header > h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
/* Style the top navigation bar */
.nav {
  width: 100vw;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
  transition: 0.2s;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: black;
    /*linear-gradient(to bottom, #d5d7e5, white, #F5F5F5, #d5d7e5);*/
  transition: background 0.5s ease out;
}

/* Style the topnav links */
.nav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
  }

/* Change color on hover */
.nav a:hover {
  background: #203a43;
    /*linear-gradient(to bottom, #43ff04, #eeffeb, #43ff04);*/

 }

/* Create three unequal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Left and right column */
.column.side {
  width: 25%;
}
 
/* Middle column */
.column.middle {
  width: 50%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column.side, .column.middle {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* Style the footer */
.footer {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Kidd Machine Works, LLC</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
 
  <!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
  (function(){
  var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  s1.async=true;
  s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/5ef7d1e34a7c6258179b774b/default';
  s1.charset='UTF-8';
  s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
  s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
  })();
  </script>
  <!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
  
<body>

<div class="header">
  <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5e306e33d98f3f2f031d3189/t/5e98f0d57b48315dcd70ed0e/1587085078151/?format=1500w" id = "logo" alt = "logo" class = "toplogo"/>
  <h3>Kidd Machine Works</h3>
  <p>123 Machine Way <br> Christiansburg, VA 24068</p>
  
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <nav>
  <li><a href="#" class="navbtn">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="navbtn">Machines</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="navbtn">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="navbtn">Quote</a></li>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column side">
    <h2>Side</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column middle">
    <h2>Main Content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column side">
    <h2>Side</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great!!  Thanks so much!  This gave me enough of a trail to kind of keep playing with it until I get it just right.  Really appreciate it!!

Comment: Happy To Help:)